# How can I set an object to be absolute but at the same time float to left when it reaches a different object

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have **two images** on my page both declared in the <***img***> tags, one is situated at the  **top left** corner and the other one at the **top right**, both are **styled** as having:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
//left: 0px; right: 0px; respectively :)
```

But when I **decrease the size of the browser window**, the **two images cross over eachother**.
How can I let the image on the right float to left when it collides with an object?

Comment: `position: absolute` removes elements from the normal flow of the document, so they don't interact moving each other anymore.

Comment: I see, well that makes it crappy! How to do it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you simply float the images and not use `position:absolute;`?

like this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7vcT6/3/)**

HTML :

```
<img class="left" src="img_path" />
<img class="right" src="img_path" />
```

CSS :

```
.left{
    float:left;
}
.right{
    float:right
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem depends by the widow sizes. I'd suggest you to use media-queries.

```
@media (max-width: [SUM OF THE IMAGES WIDTH]px) {
     // Change CSS properties of images
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use media queries to apply different styling at different viewport widths.

particularly in your case, `float: left` when the viewport is smaller than the combined width of the two images, and `position: absolute` when larger

e.g. if your images are 200px wide, each:

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
     /* css with float: left and whatever else
        your images will likely stack one under the other
     */
}

@media (min-width: 401px) {
     /* css with position: absolute and so on */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why cannot you use just `float`  `left` & `right` respectivly, one will drop when not enought room anymore. **Else** use an absolute container , and still, make your image float.

**HTML**

```
<div class="ablt-imgs"><img src="image1"/><img src="image2"/></div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .ablt-imgs {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;text-align:right;}
 .ablt-imgs img:first-of-type {float:left;}
```

[minimalistic example, part of code above](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tkJGL/)